# How do sevlet containers manage made up jsessionid(s)?

Tags: java, servlets, jsessionid

Could someone tell me what should happen if a client initiates a request to a servlet container with a made up (valid) JSESSIONID ? supposing the servlet doesn't have this jsessionid in its records (we're not hijacking a session, just making one up), will the servlet accept this session and use it for all subsequent calls or will it disregard it, make up its own jsessionid and return it to the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `HttpSession` cannot be found based on given JSESSIONID, it will just be ignored. A new one will be created whenever demanded by the code and a new JSESSIONID cookie with a new ID will be set.

Comment: Ok.. tx.. in that case, any idea how i can propagate a session created by my front to my backend through http? i want the backend to be stateful

Comment: You'd need to implement your own session manager. You can even do it at serletcontainer level. In Tomcat for example, you need to implement `org.apache.catalina.Manager` and configure in `context.xml`. Otherwise you've to maintain abstractions of the session yourself in the application scope. Be careful with this though, this is very prone to attacks. I'd rather maintain statefulness by just requiring a login and then associate the data with the particular user only.